# How to remove inherited styles using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Hello guys I have a DIV that I got passed trought a js function :

```
function print(divId) {
        var det = document.getElementById(divId);

        $(divId).removeClass();  ..
        $(divId).removeAttr();   ..        

       var mywindow = window.open(' ', 'Print');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Account Detail</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link href="../../css/reset-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        mywindow.document.write(det.innerHTML);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        }
```

I've been tryed with some jQuery functions like the showed above, buy it not works because styles are inherits from css templates, so How can I remove completly the CSS and Styles attributes completly.. I hear about YUI Reset http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/ but I don't know how to use it in a new Windows Popup

Thanks!

Comment: Do you attach a CSS file to the document loaded in the popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `.css(` [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/css) and remember to append !important if necessary to enforce overriding.

This will effectively set the `style="` attribute on the element.

Comment: jQuery could affect a dynamic parameter like divId, taking in consideration that is a div html object and I just want to apply those changes of styles in this element.

Comment: @AngelEscobedo what? Your comment makes NO sense. Doing what I said is sufficient for what you asked. What are you saying with this comment?

Comment: Because I'm using a function with a parameter that contains the entire div , so I want to know if jQuery selectors could to this job to modify Css

Comment: The selector is returning the div. The div contains children. The jQuery selector is for the div. The jQuery selector is not for the children. You don't know how this works do you?

Comment: I'm not using $(document).ready() for triggering the click on the print button, may I have to do that way? I have a Css Class for reset css and styles but don't know how to call using .Attr, I've tryed : $(divId).attr('class','reset-min.css');

Comment: does divid exist when this code is called? Is it inside a click handler?

Comment: calling it the way you expressed with `.attr('class','reset-min.css')` will have NO IMPACT.

Comment: I really think you should just post all the jQuery that you're having issues with here. You declare divid into det but them modify divid. Try modifying det instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class that overrides all the inherited properties and then just remove all the classes from the div and add the css class that overrides everything.

Comment: jquery wont resolve it, but the browser will. You aren't really "clearing" the CSS or removing it, you are just hiding properties. If you apply a global div property, for instance, there is no way to get jquery to hide that property, you can only override it with another class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to clone the target node to remove the attributes for every element therein:

```
var det = document.getElementById(divId);
if (det) {
    det = det.cloneNode();
    $(det).removeAttr("class").removeAttr("style").find("*").each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).removeAttr("class").removeAttr("style");
    });

    // …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will these help:

```
$("link[rel=stylesheet][class=must-remove-when-printing]").remove();
```

And:

```
$("*[class]").removeAttr("class");
$("*[style]").removeAttr("style");
```